# pandas group by with reset index

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, dataframe

Given I have following pandas dataframe

| UserID | LoginDate | PlacedOrderItems | Other column |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A123456 | 2023-04-01 | 1 | a |
| A123456 | 2023-04-10 | 0 | b |
| B123456 | 2023-04-05 | 0 | c |
| B123456 | 2023-04-06 | 2 | d |
| B123456 | 2023-04-07 | 0 | e |

I want to use group by `UserID` and get `min` of `LoginDate` and `max` of `PlacedOrderItems`
added to each row of my datafarme. I tried Group by but turns the column names into a weird multi level indexing.

But What I want is something like below where I preserve the original dataframe and just get two new columns added.

| UserID | LoginDate | PlacedOrderItems | Other column | min_login_date | max_order_items |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A123456 | 2023-04-01 | 1 | a | 2023-04-01 | 1 |
| A123456 | 2023-04-10 | 0 | b | 2023-04-01 | 1 |
| B123456 | 2023-04-05 | 0 | c | 2023-04-05 | 2 |
| B123456 | 2023-04-06 | 2 | d | 2023-04-05 | 2 |
| B123456 | 2023-04-07 | 1 | e | 2023-04-05 | 2 |

Comment: It sounds like what you want can be done using the [transform](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by using the groupby() method with the transform() method to create two new columns: min_login_date and max_order_items:

```
import pandas as pd


# set display options
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 10)
pd.set_option('display.width', 100)

# create the dataframe
data = {'UserID': ['A123456', 'A123456', 'B123456', 'B123456', 'B123456'],
        'LoginDate': ['2023-04-01', '2023-04-10', '2023-04-05', '2023-04-06', '2023-04-07'],
        'PlacedOrderItems': [1, 0, 0, 2, 0],
        'OtherColumn': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# convert LoginDate to datetime format
df['LoginDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['LoginDate'])

# group by UserID and transform to get the min LoginDate and max PlacedOrderItems
df['min_login_date'] = df.groupby('UserID')['LoginDate'].transform('min')
df['max_order_items'] = df.groupby('UserID')['PlacedOrderItems'].transform('max')

# group by all columns and take the first row of each group
group_cols = ['UserID', 'LoginDate', 'PlacedOrderItems', 'OtherColumn', 'min_login_date', 'max_order_items']
df = df.groupby(group_cols).first().reset_index()

# print the resulting dataframe
print(df.to_string(index=False))
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you please elaborate why you had to do last step i.e **group by all columns and take the first row of each group**

Comment: We group by all columns and take the first row of each group to keep only unique rows and remove duplicates caused by the new columns.

Answer (score 2):

Approach 1: Transform to aggregate and broadcast values

```
g = df.groupby('UserID')
df['min_login_date'] = g['LoginDate'].transform('min')
df['max_order_items'] = g['PlacedOrderItems'].transform('max')
```

Approach 2: Do a named aggregation then merge back

```
d = {'min_login_date': ('LoginDate', 'min'), 'max_order_items': ('PlacedOrderItems', 'max')}
df = df.merge(df.groupby('UserID').agg(**d))
```

---

```
    UserID   LoginDate  PlacedOrderItems Other column min_login_date  max_order_items
0  A123456  2023-04-01                 1            a     2023-04-01                1
1  A123456  2023-04-10                 0            b     2023-04-01                1
2  B123456  2023-04-05                 0            c     2023-04-05                2
3  B123456  2023-04-06                 2            d     2023-04-05                2
4  B123456  2023-04-07                 0            e     2023-04-05                2
```

Comment: Thanks first option worked. but I am getting error for second option
`MergeError: No common columns to perform merge on. Merge options: left_on=None, right_on=None, left_index=False, right_index=False`

Comment: my code 

`df= pd.DataFrame( {
                   'UserID':['A123456','A123456','B123456','B123456','B123456'],
                  'LoginDate':['2023-04-01','2023-04-10','2023-04-05','2023-04-06','2023-04-07'],
                  'PlacedOrderItems':[1,0,0,2,0],
                'Other column':['a','b','c','d','e']
                }
)`


group by  code


`
d = {'min_login_date': ('LoginDate', 'min'), 'max_order_items': ('PlacedOrderItems', 'max')}
df = df.merge(df.groupby('UserID').agg(**d))
`

Comment: Just checked for your second option after group by and agg `.reset_index()` is required because `UserID` columns gets turned into index

Comment: You can use `as_iindex=False` . Check `df.merge(df.groupby('UserID', as_index=False).agg(**d))`